# Поднятие контекста при юнит тестирование приложения Spring boot + javafx

Tags: spring, javafx, юнит-тесты, spring-boot, junit

Может кто-то может помочь/поделиться материалом по поднятию контекста при юнит тестировании приложения, написанного на Spring boot + javafx

Comment: Конечно поделимся! [Вот](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html), пожалуйста.

Comment: Спасибо, тоже находила. Но интересует именно Spring boot в связке с javafx, тк там лаунчер немного другой

Comment: Boot - это просто механизм автоматической настройки контекста, он принципиально ничего не меняет. Но есть [документация по тестированию](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html) и специально для Boot.